# Python to select drop down menus on web pages without using Selenium

Tags: python, html, dropdown

I need to use Python to open a web page, select options from drop-down lists and do some clicks all without making use of Selenium. Is there any in-built library in Python which can help me do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [Splinter](https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

This is a simple example of browser interaction using it.

```
from splinter import Browser

with Browser() as browser:
    # Visit URL
    url = "http://www.google.com"
    browser.visit(url)
    browser.fill('q', 'splinter - python acceptance testing for web applications')
    # Find and click the 'search' button
    button = browser.find_by_name('btnG')
    # Interact with elements
    button.click()
    if browser.is_text_present('splinter.readthedocs.io'):
        print("Yes, the official website was found!")
    else:
        print("No, it wasn't found... We need to improve our SEO techniques")
```